# OpenGL Lighting & Camera

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glut, lighting

I am new to OpenGL and have been facing troubles with the lighting system in OpenGL. I am using vertex normals and the vertex normal calculations seem fine when I render a unit cube or tetrahedron. When I run the code to project the tetrahedron {(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}, I get the attached output seen here.

[unit tetrahedron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmSHb.png)

[unit cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qYcc.png)

However, when I try to render a complex model, the lighting is a bit weird.

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Could you please help.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you define your normal vectors ? Can you post your 'drawMesh()' function as well ? (I suspect the problem is in there).

Comment: I have added the drawMesh function above.

Comment: I am using vertex normals, which I believe (at least in the case of the tetrahedron) is being calculated correctly.

Comment: `glNormal3f` should be called before `glVertex3f`. But this can't be the only problem. For efficiency reasons, move your `glBegin() / glEnd()` outside of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: Yep, I agree with Nico Scherlter (the line with glVertex3f needs to be swapped with the line with glNormal3f), but there is also probably a problem in the way you compute the normals. How do you initialize m_vertices[].vnormal_vec[] ?

Comment: (at least, the two lines that need to be swapped explain the appearance of the tetrahedron, for the bunny it may be something else)

Comment: This is solved. Thanks all!